# How to use one node_modules for all projects

Tags: node.js, angular

Is there an easy way to share one node_modules folders with all angular projects and thus avoiding to download same  dependencies every-time when we create a new project ?
if yes , is the method recommended ( what are pros/cons)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you using yarn or npm ?

Comment: I am using npm cli

Comment: You might want to take a look at a Node package manager named `pnpm` https://pnpm.js.org

Comment: Nice trick. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package Managers namely `npm` and `yarn` have caching mechanism.
The packages are download for the first time only and when you run the install command for the already downloaded package, they won't be downloaded again.

That being said even if you don't have an internet connection you can still install previously cached packages.

`Yarn` is particularly awesome on handling this and `npm` is now catching up.

This solves your problem of downloading the packages again. Do lock your package dependencies version. This might help in using the same node_modules for other projects too. But I don't recommend using same node_modules folder for all projects personally as this might mess the entire project. Check out [my article](https://medium.com/netscape/npm-dependency-errors-then-youre-doing-it-wrong-635160a89150) about dependency management in JS apps

Comment: Exactly. Now I figured it out . Your answer was very helpful thanks and I would definitly have a look at your article